# cocoa: how to use view-based Source List

Tags: cocoa

I want to implement an app using source list like Finder:

[image]

I have done a source list app using NSOutlineView and a tree data struct implemented by myself. I find that IB have provide a SourceList View already:

[image]

, but I don't know how to use it, I guess maybe use SourceList view will be easier to implement a Finder-like app. I want to know:

1. what's the easiest way to implement a source list app?
2. does SourceList view can show an icon before the item name ?

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're asking for. Could you edit your question to include more detail, specifically about what you're trying to accomplish? Using an outline view but not wanting to represent a tree structure is ... odd. :-) So I have to assume I've misunderstood your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this, it may help you.  http://blog.latenightsw.com/?p=352